# wildcard ssl certificate for subdomains hosted on different physical servers

Tags: ssl, subdomain, wildcard

I own a domain i.e. mysite.com, and multiple sites on subdomains i.e. service1.mysite.com, service2.mysite.com, which are hosted on different physical servers.
Now I need to secure all the sites.
Can I use a wildcard certificate or have to buy different for each site?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same wildcard certificate on all physical servers.

Note that stealing the wildcard's private key on any server will compromise the communications with all servers.